# al momento de creear una pagina web con base de datos, debo dejar todos los archivos .php O HTML?

Tags: php, html

mi pregunta es la siguiente. Estaba viendo tutoriales, veo que ellos crean el index.html y el index.php, ¿entonces debo crear un archivo index.html y uno php o como?, alguien me pude explicar esto a fondo ya que soy muy novato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que, un fichero con extesión `.html`, no es preprocesado por el intérprete  PHP del servidor web. Por lo que será entregado tal cual al cliente, para que el navegador interprete ese front-end. Es decir, no podrás hacer nada con la base de datos desde esos ficheros.

Si quieres que tu servidor web ejecute las instrucciones back-end en PHP que accedan a la base de datos, necesariamente tendrás que hacer uso de ficheros `.php`

Otra cosa que sí puedes hacer es utilizar `include()` para insertar ficheros `.html` en tu fichero `.php`. Aunque, si lo que quieres es una receta fácil, y esto sí que es opinión, utiliza ficheros `.php` para todo.